# What is the equivalent for win32com.client.GetObject() in CPP?

Tags: c++, windows, com, sap-gui

What is the equivalent for win32com.client.GetObject() in CPP ?

I am trying to get the SAPGUI object in CPP

```
SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
```

Referring to these quotes from the below article - https://blogs.sap.com/2020/08/02/sap-gui-scripting-api-from-the-past-for-future-automation/

> The SAP GUI Scripting API is in the file sapfewse.ocx (FEWSE = Front End Windows Scripting Engine), in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SapGui. It is a Component Object Model (COM) library and registered in the Windows registry. On this way you can use it from any COM-enabled programming language

Answer (score 0):

There is no "C++" way of doing it. There are, however, ways of doing it on Windows using Microsoft libraries.

I'd recommend using `CComDispatchDriver` class. Haven't tested this...but it will get you close.

```
// .. include standard windows stuff
#include <comdef.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

class ComInit
{
public:
    ComInit()
    {
        CoInitialize(NULL);
    }
    
    ~ComInit()
    {
        CoUnintialize();
    }
    
    ComInit(const ComInit& ) = delete;
    ComInit& operator=(const ComInit&) = delete;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
   ComInit _cominit;
   
   
   
   CComDispatchDriver disp;
   disp.CoCreateInstance(L"Excel.Application");
   
   _variant_t vName;
   disp.GetPropertyByName(L"Name", &vName);
   
   return 0;
}
```